# how to scroll a local div element with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scroll through a local div element using `driver.find_element_by_xpath(element).send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)`

the problem is that `element` is not an element that accepts key input, so the code throws an `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

i could rather use pyautogui to simulate mouse and keyboard functions

```
pyautogui.moveTo(663,680)
pyautogui.click(663,680)

pyautogui.scroll(-200)
time.sleep(2)
```

but i would like to keep the code inside of the browser

any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", element)
```

Comment: already did in main question